# ls: long listing format but ignore files starting with dot

Tags: shell, ls

The default behaviour of the `ls` command is to ignore files starting with dot, but if you use the long listing format with `-l` they will appear. This is inconvenient and counter intuitive for me, I want them ignored in the long listing format unless `-a` or `-A` is provided. Anyways. I skimmed over the `man` page but the only solution I found so far is to use rather hard to type `ls -l --ignore='.*'`. Is there a shorthand for that?

And if no, what's your idea of why no?

BTW. Please do not recommend aliases, bash functions etc, I'm talking about sshing to remote host I cannot/do not want to reconfigure.

UPDATE: I had a typo, I meant "dot" but originally typed "comma" because I was tired.

Comment: I expect that you have an alias defined somewhere. What does `type ls` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-have you checked that there is not some alias defined for the ls command, like `alias ls='ls -a --color=auto'` if there is you can define an alias to display the long list without displaying the hidden ones.
`alias ls='ls -l --color=auto'` so it will display the long listing without having defined the display, the listing of hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

`ls` does not ignore files starting with a comma `,`

It **does** ignore files starting with a dot `.`

Example below.  In terms of a shortcut, you could go with `ls -lI,*` or `ls -l [^,]*`

```
[steve@centos7 kak]$ find
.
./,foo
./foo
./.foo
[steve@centos7 kak]$ ls
foo  ,foo
[steve@centos7 kak]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 0 Jul  9 21:02 foo
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 0 Jul  9 20:58 ,foo
[steve@centos7 kak]$ ls -lI,*
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 0 Jul  9 21:02 foo
[steve@centos7 kak]$ ls -l [^,]*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 steve steve 0 Jul  9 21:02 foo
[steve@centos7 kak]$
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` doesn't usually list files starting with a dot. Make sure that `ls` is not aliased to 'ls -a' or `-A` if you don't want to see the files beginning with dots in `ls -l` or normal `ls` and that should fix it.